# Bring a MapFragment to the front (inside a DialogFragment)

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, supportmapfragment

I've successfully inflated a DialogFragment which then programmatically add's a MapFragment into a "target" framelayout. The map displays fine but it seems to have the dialog opaque black background over the top of it. Is there anyway to "bring it to front" per say?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The only working solution for me - enable `zOrderOnTop` flag when instantiating `SupportMapFragment`:

```
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(new GoogleMapOptions().zOrderOnTop(true));
```

You also can do this in xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   map:zOrderOnTop="true"
   ...
/>
```